# How do I download drupal from my webhost so I can run on my home server?

Tags: database

I have made a database for it in mysql and uploaded the file to my home phpmyadmin but I am not sure which files needed to configured. This is the error I get on the page:

```
 PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user   
'mydb_Rem412'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() 
(line 167 of /home/magpie/public_html/includes/lock.inc).
```

Comment: You need to adjust the username/password value in settings.php. You need to put valid username/pwd applicable on home server mysql instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer courtesy of Dipen:

"You need to adjust the username/password value in settings.php. You need to put valid username/pwd applicable on home server mysql instance."